# Use reg ex to strip numbers from a string (including negative numbers) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, expression

I'm using the following reg ex to strip numbers from a string however it also removes the (-) from negative numbers. Does anyone know of a reg ex thats leaves the numbers as well as (-). Thanks.

```
var string = "jdhjhjcdhj-200";
alert(string.replace(/[^\d]/g,""));
```

Comment: That regex removes non-numbers from the string :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `-` in your regex:

```
var string = "jdhjhjcdhj-200";
alert(string.replace(/[^\d-]/g,""));
```

It gives you `-200`

Comment: That won't delete the `-` from `abc-def`

Answer (score 1):

Include the dash in the list of excluded symbols:

```
string.replace(/[^\d\-]/g,"")
```

Answer (score 1):

The *match* method returns an array of matched patterns:

```
var string = "jdhj-hjc-dhj-200";
alert(string.match(/-?\d+/)[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex is `(?!-?\d).`

```
var string = "j-d-h-j-hjcdhj-200def-";
alert(string.replace(/(?!-?\d)./g,""));
```

Note that this will strip `abc-def-123` and make it `-123`

Test here: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2uvds

It uses negative lookahead to "ignore" minus followed by a digit and digits.

If you want to strip multiline text, you should probably use `[\s\S]` instead of `.` (read here http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)